# What is "CSS operation: data query" wait event in an Oracle StatsPack report?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Has anyone seen the `CSS operation: data query` Oracle wait event and know what it means? There was a bug [8299200](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=182300928155031&id=8299200.8&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=9ubzumayr_4) in 11.2.0.1 which is fixed in 11.2.0.3.

```
STATSPACK report for

Database    DB Id    Instance     Inst Num  Startup Time   Release     RAC
~~~~~~~~ ----------- ------------ -------- --------------- ----------- ---
          3816595344 SCRATCHEDOUT        1 04-Aug-15 14:16 11.2.0.3.0  YES

Host                             Name             Platform                CPUs
Cores Sockets   Memory (G)
~~~~ ---------------- ---------------------- ----- ----- ------- ------------
     scratchedout     Solaris[tm] OE (64-bit    48    24       6        192.0

Snapshot       Snap Id     Snap Time      Sessions Curs/Sess Comment
~~~~~~~~    ---------- ------------------ -------- --------- ------------------
Begin Snap:        237 10-Aug-15 09:00:01       42       1.1
  End Snap:        239 10-Aug-15 09:53:54       43       1.0
   Elapsed:      53.88 (mins) Av Act Sess:       0.1
   DB time:       5.45 (mins)      DB CPU:       2.46 (mins)

Cache Sizes            Begin        End
~~~~~~~~~~~       ---------- ----------
    Buffer Cache:     5,792M     5,696M   Std Block Size:         8K
     Shared Pool:     1,168M     1,264M       Log Buffer:    11,592K

Load Profile              Per Second    Per Transaction    Per Exec    Per Call
~~~~~~~~~~~~      ------------------  ----------------- ----------- -----------
      DB time(s):                0.1                0.1        0.00        0.03
       DB CPU(s):                0.1                0.0        0.00        0.01
       Redo size:          354,689.1          341,689.5
   Logical reads:            1,333.7            1,284.8
   Block changes:              158.3              152.5
  Physical reads:               33.7               32.5
 Physical writes:               46.4               44.7
      User calls:                3.6                3.5
          Parses:               13.5               13.0
     Hard parses:                2.0                1.9
W/A MB processed:                0.8                0.7
          Logons:                0.5                0.5
        Executes:               46.3               44.6
       Rollbacks:                0.0                0.0
    Transactions:                1.0

Instance Efficiency Indicators
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Buffer Nowait %:   99.97       Redo NoWait %:   99.99
            Buffer  Hit   %:   98.37  Optimal W/A Exec %:   99.96
            Library Hit   %:   93.86        Soft Parse %:   85.14
         Execute to Parse %:   70.93         Latch Hit %:   99.78
Parse CPU to Parse Elapsd %:   37.01     % Non-Parse CPU:   96.21

 Shared Pool Statistics        Begin   End
                               ------  ------
             Memory Usage %:   84.22   41.85
    % SQL with executions>1:   50.76   68.25
  % Memory for SQL w/exec>1:   75.54   68.25

Top 5 Timed Events                                                    Avg %Total
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                   wait   Call
Event                                            Waits    Time (s)   (ms)   Time
----------------------------------------- ------------ ----------- ------ ------
CPU time                                                       597          40.9
CSS operation: data query                        1,820         337    185   23.1
DFS lock handle                                 32,161          52      2    3.6
log file parallel write                         16,038          51      3    3.5
CSS initialization                                  21          30   1428    2.1
          -------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note you provided is regarding issues with shutdown: Bug 8299200 - Shutdown immediate hangs (Doc ID 8299200.8). Is it the correct doc you wanted to refer?

Have you recently upgraded to 11.2.0.3?

If so, there's this MOSC note that might be helpful, referring to a bug that causes Clusterware Synchronization Services operations to be very slow, leading to the css-related wait events:

[Doc ID 1444483.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=192437293453095&id=1444483.1&displayIndex=7&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=epd3qui6l_437#CAUSE/)

Comment: Thank you! When I searched for `CSS operation: data query`, the article Doc ID 8299200.8 was the only hit I got. I noticed Doc ID 1444483.1 refers to the wait event as `CSS operation: query`. My bad, I should have searched more broadly.